# Does B2C Lock An Account After N Failed Attempts?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

How does B2C handle this situation?  I couldn't find anything on [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Azure AD B2C does provide password lockout.** The logic and duration is not a straight forward, "lock out X minutes with exponential cooldown after Y wrong password attempts." There's an intelligent and evolving algorithm that considers many other signals to disambiguate between bad actors and mistakes and other benign scenarios.

Read more about in the [Azure AD B2C Threat Management documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-threat-management)

Comment: Saca, can you please also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49504618/azure-ad-b2c-tenant-seems-corrupted-after-using-aad-graph-client. I don't know why all admins, when attempting to log into AAD B2C through the Azure Portal are hitting this account lockout, and I don't know how to unlock the accounts. (Sorry if this is the wrong place to put this comment - I just really need help!)

Comment: Hi Saca. the document that you mentioned contains instructions to configure the lockout threshold for B2C. But it does not seem to have an effect. I raised it to 20 but still get "user has exceeded maximum for self-asserted step" on the 6th try. Can you clarify if that works for B2C, as it says in the document?