# How to test the lockout policy of azure ad b2c

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

We are using Azure AD B2C as the authentication provider for our project. One facility that we lack in AD B2C is locking of an account on multiple invalid login attempts. There seems to be an algorithm which will block login requests temporarily for a certain period of time but will be allowed to log in again after the time.

but also, As per the documentation : 
"By using various signals, Azure AD B2C analyzes the integrity of requests. Azure AD B2C is designed to intelligently differentiate intended users from hackers and botnets. Azure AD B2C provides a sophisticated strategy to lock accounts based on the passwords entered, in the likelihood of an attack."

Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-threat-management#password-attacks

how will the account get locked out? 
how can one go about testing that it will actually happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does B2C Lock An Account After N Failed Attempts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45981903/does-b2c-lock-an-account-after-n-failed-attempts)

Answer (score 2):

Today, the number of attempts begins at 10 and adjusts itself after that depending on the nature of each attempted logins.  Other risks, such as attacks from suspicious IP addresses are addressed differently.  Lockout time increases over time to create friction on automated attackers.

Answer (score 1):

Use different passwords for 10 times (if the **Lockout threshold** is not changed), your account will get locked.

Eg:

attempt 1 => password: 1

attempt 2 => password: 12

attempt 3 => password: 123

....

attempt 10 => password: 1234567890

Comment: Had the same question and tried this. I indeed succesfully get a lock-out error after 10 different passwords. Thanks!

Comment: But if I login with the correct password immediately after the threshold number of attempts with wrongs password ,  I am able to sign in ideally,  which should have prevented me. Any other checks we need to see here ?

Comment: @coder89 Please check the **Lockout duration in seconds**, until that time user account will be get blocked even if correct password is entered by the user.

Comment: @Alex but that's not happening, I am able to login even before the Lockout duration in seconds expires. Confirmed the sign in activity logs as well shows that "Account is locked...".

Comment: @coder89 I checked same in my instance, that worked as expected. Even I entered the correct password B2C shown the locked message.

Comment: I am also trying but i am not getting the lockout message at all even after trying more than 10 times which is default lockout threshold. I though this feature is by default on but does not seem to work in my tenant. Am i missing something?

Comment: "because each Azure AD datacenter tracks lockout independently, it might take more than your defined lockout threshold number of attempts to cause a lockout" — from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/threat-management#testing-the-password-protection-settings