# Unblocking Azure AD B2C users who cannot register (email verification failing with "too many retries"

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

A few users who want to register using our sign-in/sign-up policy have reported that the email verification is failing with an error about "too many retries" this are valid users we need to allow to register, however, since they have not registered, I can't even see them on the users list.

Is there any way (UI, PowerShell, API) to unlock/re-enable the users?

Comment: Maybe related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45983010/185123?  They won't have user records until they complete the sign-up.

Comment: Thank you, it would make sense, as they probably use many of the same threat mitigation strategies as regular Azure AD. However, the email is getting blocked from email validation, I can't find logs or a way to allow this user to complete registration.

Comment: I’ve temporary glitches with login that say the same thing.  Reach out to @azuread on Twitter or better yet azuresupport on Twitter